# Printing list gives two different results

Tags: python

So, I have this code (slightly modified)

```
def allBoards(fen, solution):
   board = [['1'],['2'],['3'],['4'],['5'],['6'],['7'],['8']]
   board[0] = fenToBoard(fen)  

   for i in range(6):
       board[i+1] = boardUpdater(board[i], solution, i)
       print(board[i+1])
    
   print(board)
   return board
```

The print-statement in the for-loop produces a different output compared to the second print-statement in my code. The print-statement in the for-loop prints the updated version of each element correctly, whereas the other print-statement prints:

```
[board[7], board[7], board[7], board[7], board[7], board[7], board[7], ['8']]
```

What goes wrong? My output is very heavy, so it is omitted.

Thanks in advance.

---

The inputs to this function is two strings:

```
fen = '6k1/pb1p1pp1/1p3n1p/8/2PN1Q2/2qB1P2/P4KPP/3Rr3'
solution = 'e1d1 f4b8 b7c8 b8c8 f6e8 c8e8'
```

The fenToBoard function returns a list of lists, like this:

```
def fenToBoard(fen):
   fenRows = re.split('/| |-', fen)[0:8]

   boardRows = []
   for fenRow in fenRows:
      fenRow = list(fenRow) 
      for letter in fenRow:
         if set(letter).issubset({"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"}):
            pos = fenRow.index(letter)
            emptySpace = list(int(letter) * '-')
            fenRow[pos:pos+1] = emptySpace
       boardRows.append(fenRow)    
   return boardRows
```

The boardUpdater function is very similar to fenToBoard

Comment: Can you give us some input examples? You have two other functions that are not mentioned.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your message @SorooshNoorzad. I will try to update my question with some input examples.

Comment: @ozturkdk What exactly is wrong with the output of your second print? Could you add an expected output? ( Is it the trailing `['8']`? Then that would be because of `range(6)` instead of `range(7)` ) Have a nice day!

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. There is ALOT of noise in your question. Many irrelevant details. Just create a minimal snippet that produces the same error with clear inputs and the output you expect

Comment: What is `boardUpdater`?

Comment: @wuerfelfreak The second print is wrong because it prints [board[7], board[7], board[7], board[7], board[7], board[7], board[7], ['8']]. I'm expecting [board[1], board[2], board[3], board[4], board[5], board[6], board[7], ['8']]. I'm explicitly saying in the for-loop that the entires should be updated according to the associated index.

Comment: @kaya3 I will make a new, more elegant thread if I don't get the question solved on my own. I will clarify all the functions I'm using in the new question.

Comment: No, do not create a new question with the required details, edit this one.

Answer (score 1):

```py
fen = '6k1/pb1p1pp1/1p3n1p/8/2PN1Q2/2qB1P2/P4KPP/3Rr3'
solution = 'e1d1 f4b8 b7c8 b8c8 f6e8 c8e8'

def fenToBoard(fen):
  
   fenRows = fen.split('/'or'|'or' 'or'|'or'-')[0:8]

   boardRows = []
   for fenRow in fenRows:
      fenRow = list(fenRow) 
      for letter in fenRow:
          if set(letter).issubset({"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"}):
            pos = fenRow.index(letter)
            emptySpace = list(int(letter) * '-')
            fenRow[pos:pos+1] = emptySpace
      boardRows.append(fenRow)    
   return boardRows
fenToBoard('6k1/pb1p1pp1/1p3n1p/8/2PN1Q2/2qB1P2/P4KPP/3Rr3')
```

`output`

```
[['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'k', '-'],
 ['p', 'b', '-', 'p', '-', 'p', 'p', '-'],
 ['-', 'p', '-', '-', '-', 'n', '-', 'p'],
 ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
 ['-', '-', 'P', 'N', '-', 'Q', '-', '-'],
 ['-', '-', 'q', 'B', '-', 'P', '-', '-'],
 ['P', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'K', 'P', 'P'],
 ['-', '-', '-', 'R', 'r', '-', '-', '-']]
```

Comment: Hi @Hercules. Can you provide a solution on how to make this work then?

Comment: This isn't a school project or anything. It's a spare time project I'm working on for my self. Maybe you can clarify your answer a bit, then I can try to solve it on my own.

Comment: I don't understand why the board list doesn't get updated, when I explicitly update the entries in the for-loop.

Comment: @ozturkdk Bro it update explicity in loop but only update the even index entries.It should update logically.

Comment: @Hercules A answers on StackOverflow is meant to fully answer the question. Tips like this can be given via commenting, which you will be able to do when you reach sufficient reputation. Please add more context to your question so that it is useful to future visitors. Have a nice day!

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with the fenToBoard. Why did you modify it?

Comment: @ozturkdk  Because Inline 2 of fenToBoard is `re` that is not defined and for my better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code. This could be solved after storing it in a var.

```
def allBoards(fen, solution):
    board = [['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['5'], ['6'], ['7'], ['8']]


board[0] = fenToBoard(fen)

for i in range(6):
    board[i + 1] = boardUpdater(board[i], solution, i)
    x = board[i + 1]
    print(x)

print(x)
return x
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. This wont work because I only print the last element of board.